# Capture volume control button event on Android

Tags: android, event-handling, android-audiomanager

Used the following code to capture volume control button events.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    int action = event.getAction();
    Log.i("Volume", "Volume " + keyCode + " " + action);
        AudioManager audio = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:
            if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                audio.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, AudioManager.ADJUST_RAISE, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
            }
            return true;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:
            if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                audio.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, AudioManager.ADJUST_LOWER, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
            }
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        }
}
```

but when the volume bar toast is shown it doesn't capture the volume button press events anymore unless the toast is gone.

Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to just capture the button presses to adjust the volume, maybe you should instead just call [`setVolumeControlStream()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setVolumeControlStream%28int%29) when initializing your Activity?

From the [developer site](http://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/volume-playback.html#HardwareVolumeKeys):

> You may be tempted to try and listen for volume key presses and modify the volume of your audio stream that way. Resist the urge. Android provides the handy setVolumeControlStream() method to direct volume key presses to the audio stream you specify.

Comment: Setting the volume isn't the only thing I need to do. I need to do some custom actions on volume change/button press. Hence I need to capture the button press events.

Comment: Got it, I was just hoping to reduce unnecessary code if possible :) Anyway, I just tested your code and I seem to be getting the key events even when the volume bar toast is shown. This is on an emulator with stock ICS virtual device. Are you sure you are not getting the key events?

Comment: yes as long as the volume up/down toast is showing, it doesn't capture button press events unless the toast is gone.

Comment: Interesting, something else might have been preventing the event to be captured. Maybe you can add your `onKeyDown()` code in an empty test activity to try whether you are getting the event there? That is basically what I do and confirm that I am getting it even with the toast shown. Not sure if this could be a device specific issue, maybe you can test your code on the emulator too.